# Intentionally crashing C application with memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am fairly new to C. I am currently learning about memory leaks, and I am trying to create one with a simple C program. I am supposed to run the until it crashes, but when I run it, the memory used peaks at around 95%. Is my code not a memory leak? Is it possible with paging on? 
Here is the code that I am trying:

```
int main(void) {
    while (1)
    {
        char *newArea = malloc(10);
        char *mainArea = malloc(10000);
        mainArea = newArea;
    }
}
```

Comment: try writing into the space

Comment: Your code is leaking memory, but cannot crash because of you are not using the mallocated memory.

Comment: You should check the return value of your malloc.  If you get 0, then it was unable to allocate the memory.

Comment: M.M I do not understand your comment (New to this). LPs so how would i go about using the mallocated memory? Would you suggest a different method?

Comment: @Greg M.M means something like `char* mainArea = malloc(10000);
 if(mainArea != NULL) mainArea[0] = 'x';`

Comment: @CiaPan Yeah thats not working either.

Comment: The failure condition will be that `malloc` returns `NULL` when it can no longer satisfy your request.  When that happens, your loop will just keep calling `malloc` and getting `NULL` over and over, which is what you're seeing.  You need to check the return value, and if it's `NULL`, print an error message.

Comment: @TomKarzes The thing is I need to know how much memory the program has used before it can not continue. Is there an error that i can return with that shows the memory used? Or should I find it with task manager or something.

Comment: Who says it has to crash? C standard does not specify any crashing conditions. It specifically says, it is OK to not crash in quite a many situations.

Comment: I do? Im not worried about C standard at the moment.

Comment: Ok, so here's what you do.  First, forget the tiny `malloc(10)`, it's useless, delete it.  You can also delete the useless assignment to `mainArea` after the `malloc` call.  Then, pick some big size, like 10000 or 100000, or perhaps a power of two - it doesn't matter much.  Then keep a count of how many times you called `malloc` before it returned `NULL`.  The amount you successfully allocated is then `count * size`.

Comment: @TomKarzes i got a count of 21117, using malloc(100000), so i have 2.1*10^9 bits. That doesnt sound like much. Thats only 200 MB

Comment: Well 21,117 * 100,000 is 2,111,100,000 bytes.  In hex, that's 0x7DDDFC20, which is about half of a 32-bit address space.  So for a 32-bit system, that looks right.

Comment: My computer is a 64 bit system @TomKarzes

Comment: Ok, in that case I suggest checking two things:  (1) Make sure you're compiling for 64 bits, and (2) See if you have any per-process memory limits in place.  In Unix, look at `getrlimit()` and `setrlimit()`.  You can also access the limits with the `limit` command in `csh`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Actually i found out that Visual Studio isnt 64 bit, so you were correct, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Greg What do you mean by 'thats not working'? I think it works, in a way described at the same time by Lundin in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37203108/733637), namely it causes a memory 'declared for use' by a call to `malloc()` to be 'touched' (actually used) and consequently actually allocated in RAM.

Comment: @CiaPan At that time i did not understand what your code meant, but Tom has cleared that air

Answer (score 4):

In order to make programs faster and less memory consuming, many OS don't allocate any dynamic memory before the point where you actually use it. Your code never uses the dynamic memory, so the OS probably does not allocate anything, it just reserves that memory.

So if you just try to write somewhere inside the allocated memory, you should run out of memory as expected, as you will then force the OS to perform the actual allocation.

Comment: So what would be a way that I could use the mallocated memory to crash the application?

Comment: In addition, writing to the "allocated" memory will make it crash the first time the allocation request cannot be satisfied and `NULL` is returned, which dereferencing will cause a segmentation fault...

Answer (score -1):

What you do is just exhausting the available memory, and you can do that simpler – just allocate memory and forget it:

```
int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        (void) malloc(10000);
    }
    return 0;  // will never get here!
}
```

Memory leak, however, is something else – it is allocating memory for some task and not disposing it after. For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    while (StillSomethingToDo())
    {
        char *membuffer = malloc(10000);

        DoSomethingWithTheBuffer(membuffer);

        // forget to free(membuffer)
    }
    return 0; // will return normally
}
```

After the loop terminates when `StillSomethingToDo()` returns 'false' the `main()` proceeds to `return`, however there are some blocks on the heap (lots of them, possibly) which were not `free`-d. And they can't be freed anymore, because the pointers to them (all the previous values of `membuffer` variable) are lost.

Comment: But the moment the process ends, all the memory it allocated (used or not) is freed.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Of course! All the memory allocated by the system to the process goes back to the system when the process terminates. However some processes are designed to work for a long time, or even not to terminate at all until the system goes down – for example system services. And this is the case where memory leaks cause most troubles, because 1) it wastes system resources, and 2) the forgotten memory volume hits the system's per-process treshold eventually, which makes the process to terminate too soon.